# Any inexpensive visa to exit Beijing airport for less than 24 hours?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, schengen-visas, air-china, china-airlines

I am planning to book a flight from Munich(Germany) to Sydney(Australia) by China Airlines. Most of the connections with China airlines have a layover duration between 13-20 hours.

Since the Chinese visa is too expensive (more than 200 Euros), I am wondering if I have some inexpensive option to exit the airport and visit Beijing city for a short duration (i.e. less than 24 hours)?

[Here, it says that citizens of any country can have a 24-hour free Transit Visa. But I am not sure if it means that I can exit the airport.](http://ee.china-embassy.org/eng/tzygg/t1460983.htm)

**PS:** I have a Permanent Schengen Visa and Indian passport.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the 24 hour visa-free transit to leave the airport. After you go through immigration you will be landside anyway, so it would not be possible to prevent it! Just go directly to immigration and be prepared to show the boarding pass for your onward flight.

Comment: Just be aware that these rules are fairly new so if you ask people other than immigrations they might say no, but as Michael rightly points out it is perfectly clear just verify that your passport is one that is valid for this type of transit VISA